# Quel temps dois-je utiliser en traduisant : le passé composé ou l'imparfait ?

Tags: grammaire, traduction, temps-grammatical, passé-composé, imparfait

J'ai une phrase comme ci-dessous :

> When he was a child, they lived in a cottage in the jungle

Quelle traduction est correcte ?

1. Quand il était enfant, ils vivaient dans une petite maison dans la jungle
2. Quand il était enfant, ils ont vécu dans une petite maison dans la jungle
3. Quand il a été enfant, ils ont vécu dans une petite maison dans la jungle
4. Quand il a été enfant, ils vivaient dans une petite maison dans la jungle

En d'autres termes, en traduisant je dois utiliser de quelle temps :

1. Imparfait, Imparfait
2. Impartfait, Passé Composé
3. Passé Composé, Passé Composé
4. Passé Composé, Imparfait

Comment: Imparfait partout (sauf s'il y a un contexte particulier autour de cette phrase ("for a while", par exemple), auquel cas le 2. pourrait être meilleur).

Comment: Dans quelle situation pourrais-je utiliser de cas le 2. ?

Comment: "Quand il était enfant, ils ont vécu dans une petite maison dans la jungle _pendant quelques mois_."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Quand il était enfant, ils vivaient dans une petite maison dans la jungle** : à utiliser dans la plupart des cas. Les deux actions sont étendues dans la durée, c'est l'imparfait qu'il faut utiliser.

**Quand il était enfant, ils ont vécu dans une petite maison dans la jungle [...]** : à utiliser si la phrase se poursuit et indique des précisions (durée, contexte) qui feraient privilégier le passé composé.

Answer (score 1):

Quand il était enfant, ils vivaient dans une petite maison dans la jungle. L'imparfait est le temps de la narration.

Le passé simple devrait idéalement remplacer le passé composé dans la narration écrite. Donc: Quand il était enfant, ils vécurent (quelques mois) dans une petite maison dans la jungle.